# Disable Selected Item highlight on Listpicker WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

How do i disable the highlight of the selected item of an listpicker in Windows Phone 7?
I guess i'll have to make some sort of style in Microsoft Blend but i don't have any experience in that program so a litle bit of help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need blend to create styles.  What are you trying to do?  Maybe there's a better control that you can use.

Comment: Okey, you have any experience in doing it using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list.SelectedIndex = -1;
```